# Teradata macro sometimes works fine sometimes runs forever with no reply

Tags: sql, macros, wildfly, teradata

Teradata macro sometimes works fine sometimes runs forever with no reply and no error in log
i should terminate the session from the viewpoint
Note : their is no sequence to track the error, this problem appears only once from 36000 request per day and if i used the same parameters of the macro which caused the forever execution on Tearadata sql assistant or from my application it works fine and it returns a value

"""""

i terminated the query
using query timeout in wildfly

Comment: If there's some kind of block/deadlock, you can try to find the session in Viewpoint using rewind. To avoid locks add LOCK ROW ACCESS to the SELECT used in the macro.

Comment: the selection is from views not a table and LOCK ROW ACCESS are used in the views used

Comment: ACCESS lock can still be blocked by EXCLUSIVE lock. If the query was delayed or blocked or executing "forever" you should be able to find it in Viewpoint history using "rewind" to that point in time as dnoeth says, which can provide a clearer understanding of the underlying issue.